# Dual boot Vista/Win7. Can I install VMware and run the Vista OS already installed from the physical HDD?

Tags: windows, vmware

This is part of a migration from Vista to Windows7. I now have a dual boot computer, with Win7 the preferred OS. From time to time I might need to go back to Vista to see how the things were configured there and then I will need to go back to Win7 to configure/install the same app there.
This is a computer that had very complex settings and it was difficult and risky to upgrade in place, to install Win7 over Vista.

In order to avoid countless reboots I would like to be able to always run Win7 and when I need I would like to be able to fire up VMWare Workstation and to start a Vista Machine that would have as HDD the physical HDD where currently Vista resides. I would expect the VMWare machine to run the OS installed on that HDD and I would expect Vista no to see that the hardware changed. My apps are not hardware dependent.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible and there are a few ways you could go about doing this.

The Easy Way
VMware Desktop allows you to use your existing partition/Disk to boot from only if its an IDE Disk.
https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_disk_dualboot.html

The hard way
You can capture the Windows Vista OS as an .wim image with Windows Deployment Tool ImageX.exe. Then use other tools to create a bootable ISO. You would have to update the image though every time you feel there are a lot of changes made in Vista you want to see in VMware.